# Make a tuple of arbitrary size functionally in Julia

Tags: function, tuples, julia

An ordinary way to make a tuple in Julia is like this:

```
n = 5
t2 = (n,n) # t2 = (5,5)
t3 = (n,n,n)# t3 = (5,5,5)
```

I want to make a tuple of arbitrary size functionally.

```
n = 5
someFunction(n,size) = ???

t10 = someFunction(n,10) # t10 = (5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
```

How can I realize this?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is [`ntuple`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.ntuple) ?

```
julia> ntuple(_ -> 5, 10)
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Note that, you can also use `tuple` or `Tuple`:

```
julia> tuple((5 for _ in 1:10)...)
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)

julia> Tuple(5 for _ in 1:10)
(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Note that ntuple can take a method argument's type parameter as its length to become a type-stable call, e.g. `f(e, a::Val{X}) where {X} = ntuple(_ -> e, X)` results in a type-stable `f( 10, Val(3) )`. The other ways don't have this benefit; the compiler can't figure out that the comprehension `(e for _ in 1:X)` and the resulting Tuple must have a fixed length X.